# Counting the number of transmissions in TinyOS 2.x

Tags: tinyos, nesc

I'm trying to implement an application in NesC able to count the number of transmissions performed along the simulation, however I'm facing many difficulties. No approach that I tryed works. Could anyone help me? this is my application:

module FloodingC {

```
uses {
    interface Boot;
    interface SplitControl as AMControl;
    interface Timer<TMilli> as MilliTimer;
    interface Receive;
    interface AMSend;
    interface Packet;
    interface AMPacket;
    interface RootControl;
    interface PacketAcknowledgements as PackAck;
}
```

}

implementation {

```
message_t packet;

bool locked = FALSE;
uint16_t flag;

event void Boot.booted() {
    flag = 0;
    call AMControl.start();
}

event void AMControl.startDone(error_t err) {
    if(err == SUCCESS) {
        if(TOS_NODE_ID == 1)
            call RootControl.setRoot();


        call MilliTimer.startOneShot(1024);
    }
    else {
        call AMControl.start();
    }
}

event void AMControl.stopDone(error_t err) {
}

void sendMsg(){
    floodingMsg_t* msg = (floodingMsg_t* ) call Packet.getPayload(&packet, sizeof(floodingMsg_t));
    if(msg == NULL) {   
        return;
    }
    flag = 1; 
    msg->nodeid = TOS_NODE_ID;
    msg->counter = 1;
    call PackAck.requestAck(&packet);
    if(call AMSend.send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, &packet, sizeof(floodingMsg_t)) == SUCCESS) {
        locked = TRUE;
    }
}

event void MilliTimer.fired() {

    if(locked) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        if (call RootControl.isRoot()){
            sendMsg();
        }
    }
}

event void AMSend.sendDone(message_t *msg, error_t error){
    if (call PackAck.wasAcked(msg) == SUCCESS){
        locked = FALSE;
    }
    else{
        sendMsg();
    }
}

event message_t* Receive.receive(message_t* msg, void* payload, uint8_t len) {
    floodingMsg_t* newMsg = (floodingMsg_t* )payload;

    if (locked == TRUE) return msg;

    if(flag == 0) {
        flag = 1;
        newMsg->nodeid = TOS_NODE_ID;
        newMsg->counter++;
        call AMSend.send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, msg, call Packet.maxPayloadLength());

    }

    return msg;
}
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can count them using a BaseStation sniffer (included in tinyos), or adding a sequence number on your transmitted packet.